# navbar dropdown menu does not expand

Tags: html, css

I am using Bootstrap navbar classes and I cannot get the dropdown to expand when clicking on it.

I have followed this post [Can't expand navbar dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525835/cant-expand-navbar-dropdown-menu) but my code seems to follow what is suggested there. The text does disappear (the hidden-sm) based on viewport but the drop down links for change password and log off do not display. Any help is appreciated.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/" title="Events">Event List</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="far fa-user"></i> <span class="hidden-sm">User name</span> <i class="caret"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="/Account/ChangePassword" title="">Change Password</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Account/LogOut" title="End your session and return to the log in screen">Log Off</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: can u plz add this in codepen?

Comment: I have updated your question and now its working . Also added this as my answer. Thanks

Comment: @NipunTharuksha I have local references to bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js

Comment: Omg sorry Yeah Im trying to resolve it

Comment: which version of bootstrap you are using in your local project setup